# What is the proper cast from void* to long?

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm using `posix_memalign` (had trouble with `align_alloc`) to allocate (inside my own `new`) so I have a `void*`. I need it as int for instance to compute alignment:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main() {

  void *ptr;
  auto align{4096}, size{10000};
  posix_memalign( &ptr,align,size );
  cout << ptr << endl; // works
  cout << ptr % align << endl; // not

  return 0;
}
```

I thought in modern C++ `static_cast<long>` would be the right way , but that gives an error that that's not allowed on a `void*`. So what is the proper way? I can of course use old-style C casts, but I'm trying to avoid those.

Comment: the question is unclear. What is the problem when you try to print the value of a `void*`? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You're right. Printing as such works; the trouble came from computing with it.

Answer (score 9):

You can't `static_cast` a pointer to a non-pointer type. You may have to use `reinterpret_cast`:

```cpp
reinterpret_cast<long>(ptr);
```

Also since you want to get a pointer address as an integer, it's better to use `intptr_t` present in `stdint.h` (which is made for this purpose):

```cpp
reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr);
```

Comment: What is undefined behaviour? The solution I gave works pretty well.

Comment: I overlooked both the question and your answer (hence the downvote, now reversed). This made me check `reinterpret_cast`-related rules. So there it is: [`[expr.reinterpret.cast]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4.sentence-1) _"A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold all values of its type."_

Answer (score 0):

to just print the address

std::cout << "Pointer address = 0x" << void_pointer_var << std::endl;

presuming void_pointer_var is of type void*, this will print its value in hex.

if its relevant for it to be in decimal then use a reinterpret cast